# Does Google Publish WSDLs for their SOAP/XML APIs?

Tags: xml, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, wsdl, storage

Hoping to tap into your collective knowledge and understand if Google published WSDLs or any other programmatic discovery document for their XML APIs.
For example, there is a discovery document for their JSON API for storage: https://storage.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1
But nothing that I can find published for the XML API for storage: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview

Docs are nice but programmatic discovery is essential

I've googled around for a WSDL to no avail

Comment: The schema of the data is controlled by organizations, not Google.  Google is just a tool that is used to send/receive the data.  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

Comment: Do you have a specific API in mind that you XML? If you speak about Storage, it's not SOAP, it's only XML. Why do you need to use the API directly? Can't you use the client library instead?

Comment: Thanks [guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) I appreciate your response and your frequent involvement in Q&A re: GCP.
My use case is maintaining an accurate inventory of available methods for both the JSON and XML APIs in Google Cloud, cataloging the permissions, resulting event names, and threats against the API methods/actions.  Maintaining this inventory is clunky and inefficient without a programmatic source of truth for the XML API.
The discovery documents for the JSON API are great but I'm left without a great solution for the XML APIs